# Django: Template Context Processor declare all functions in one tuple entry

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to declare all of your custom template context processor functions in one tuple entry?

```
# Templates Related Settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "myapp.context_processors.remote_ip_address_processor"
)
```

In `context_processors.py`:

```
def remote_ip_address_processor(request):
    return {'REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']}
```

and we can use globally in all templates via the tag `{{ REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS }}`.

What if our `context_processors.py` contains like 10 different processors (functions)? Do we have to list each and every one of them in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` tuple or can declare them all at once by file like `"myapp.context_processors.*"`? I know the wildcard won't work but something along those lines. It gets annoying to have to declare multiple functions within the same `context_processors.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother having multiple functions at all? They're all going to be used on every request anyway, so there's no point separating them out. Just return everything from one function in a single dictionary.

Comment: Yes, we can do that but what if we don't use them all for every single request? Some will be used for certain conditions and some won't. Wouldn't it put a load on the system if we do some calculations and return everything from one huge single dictionary composed of other little dictionaries for each and every request even though that particular data will not be used?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Firstly, you wouldn't have a dictionary of dictionaries, just a single dict. And secondly, how are you determining now whether you need the data or not? You can't dynamically modify TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, so your functions must have some logic in them: you can use exactly the same logic in one single function.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare one by one like:

"**django.core.context_processors**.debug",
"**django.core.context_processors**.i18n",
"**django.core.context_processors**.media",
"**django.core.context_processors**.static",

It must be set like this because there is a precedence order between the entries.